# Operation Timeout for port number

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am try to send mail using below code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mailserver");

mail.From = new MailAddress("mailid");
mail.To.Add("mailid");
mail.Subject = "Test";
mail.Body = "Report";

//Console.WriteLine(SmtpServer.Port +"......"+ SmtpServer.Host);

SmtpServer.Port = 465;

SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mailid", "pwd");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Timeout = 40000;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Exception:

> Operation Timeout for port no. 465 port and works fine for port no. 587

Comment: Are you trying to send an email message locally, or are your planning to send it via Internet?

Comment: So what is the problem to use port 587?

Comment: What is your question? How to set up a proper mail server or configure your network properly or how to find out the correct information to use in your code or?

Comment: I am sending mail via internet and I have already check with telnet weather the port is open or not on my machine. The port is also open.

Comment: Typical reasons why this would happen (telnet works but app doesn't) would be if a firewall (e.g. Windows Firewall) is blocking outgoing traffic on your PC. Either add your app (and VS) to the whitelist, or temporarily stop all firewalls. Another reason could be that the remote protocol isn't SMTP + SSL?